# Only load Snipcart on specific page in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, jamstack, snipcart

I'm using Snipcart Plugin in Gatsby but the script gets loaded everywhere. Is is it possible with some sort of function to trigger the script on only 1 specific page and not entirely?

Below are the options I'm using in my Gatsby-config.js file

```
{
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-snipcart",
      options: {
        apiKey: process.env.SNIPCART_API,
        autopop: true,
        js: "https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.8/default/snipcart.js",
        styles: "https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.8/default/snipcart.css",
        jquery: false,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [gatsby-plugin-snipcartv3](https://github.com/danielholdsworth/gatsby-plugin-snipcartv3). I believe the gatsby-plugin-snipcart is deprecated and is not working with Snipcart v3.

But as far as I know, there's no way to tell the plugin to load the script only on specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Snipcart directly, not using the plugin, to have more control over it.

Let's say you have a `layout.js` file, wrapping content for your page, you can have a `loadSnipcart` flag that will load Snipcart files only when you need them.

Here's an example:

#### layout.js

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

export default ({ loadSnipcart, children }) => {
    const Snipcart = () => {
        if (!loadSnipcart) return null

        return (
            <Helmet>
                <script
                    src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.8/default/snipcart.js"
                    type="text/javascript"
                />
                <link
                    href="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.8/default/snipcart.css"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                />
            </Helmet>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div id="main-content">
            <Snipcart />
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### shop.js

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "./layout"

export default () => {
    return (
        <Layout loadSnipcart>
            <h1>Welcome to my shop !</h1>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

#### index.js

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "./layout"

export default () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>This page doesn't load Snipcart</h1>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```